# how to integrate progress indicator for each dynamic item of longlistselector in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Actually LonglistSelector bind with a dynamic list of image uri. i need to display loading indicator for each  image until image loaded. If anybody knows how to make it done please help me Immediately. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you share some code where you want to show progress indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to provide a list of objects that know the following:

- Image URL
- Loading Indicator

The LonglistSelector Item Template would then display the Loading animation as long as LoadingIndicator is true. As soon as it becomes false, it would display the image.
This can be achieved using the Visibility property and a BooleanToVisibilityConverter class.

The model stated on top must implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the loading indicator to get the automatic UI refresh for each item as soon as it got changed.

Your model would look like this. The refered class BindableBase is a class from Microsoft which can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/windows/apps/xx130657.aspx

```
public class ImageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// No need to use SetProperty here, because this parameter is not bound against any UI control
    /// which would need a refresh
    /// </summary>
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    private bool isLoading;
    /// <summary>
    /// Reflects loading status of the underlying tile.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get { return isLoading; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isLoading, value); }
    }

    private ImageSource imageContent;
    /// <summary>
    /// Reflects image which shall be displayed.
    /// </summary>
    public ImageSource ImageContent
    {
        get { return imageContent; }
        set { SetProperty(ref imageContent, value); }
    }
}
```

Your UI would bind against a list of those model entities and display the loading animation when isLoading is true, else the image. For this, you can use the BooleanToVisibilityConverter class which is most of the time created together with new projects. But you may search for the class online.

Now when your page is loaded, you iterate through your list of items and start downloading the image. Once you have downloaded it, replace the "ImageContent" with the actual image and set IsLoading to false. Your UI will then display the image and hide the loading animation because both properties are notitied to the UI.

Your data template would look something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplateLongListSelector"> 
    <StackPanel Width="230" Height="290" Margin="4,4"> 
        <Image Width="230" Height="290" Stretch="UniformToFill" Visibility="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource BooleanNegationToVisibilityConverter}}"> 
            <Image.Source> 
                <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageSource}"/> 
            </Image.Source> 
        </Image> 
        <TextBlock Text="Loading..." Visibility="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    </StackPanel> 
</DataTemplate>
```

The converter classes needed:

```
public sealed class BooleanNegationToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value is bool && (bool)value) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}

public sealed class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value is bool && (bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Both need to be declared in your App.xaml resource dictionary section:

```
<common:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
<common:BooleanNegationToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanNegationToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

"common" is defined in App.xaml on top:

```
<Application
...
xmlns:common="clr-namespace:YourProject.Path.To.Converter.Classes"
...>
```

Comment: Thanks eX0du5. My each item contain 4 no. of image_url Like {image_url1,image_url2,image_url3,image_url4} to display four no. of image at a time in tabular form of two rows and two column. will i take loading_indicator property for each image_url???

Comment: This is my Item template, would u please tell me what change needed to meet requirement..                                  <DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplateLongListSelector">
            <StackPanel Width="230" Height="290"  Margin="4,4">
                <Image Width="230" Height="290" Stretch="UniformToFill">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>